# Make every page of a PDF into an image (contained in a pdf) in C#

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I have a lot of PDF files with text. To prevent copying, I added a watermark, however, the watermark is easily removable simply by editing the PDF.

Using C#, how can I convert a PDF into a PDF with each page being an image of the text? I understand this isn't foolproof, as OCR can be used to extract the text, but I want to make it that little bit harder.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Show us your attempt at coding it please. What library are you using to work with the PDF?

Comment: All that will do is make legitimate use harder. You can not text search in a image.

Comment: Find a PDF printer that has a "print as image" option and enable it, then print your PDFs to that PDF printer. I use Foxit PDF and it's print driver has this option, though I've no idea how easy it is to control programmatically. Perhaps saving it as a default will suffice

Comment: I assume the watermark is only part of the trial? If I purchased something and a watermark was on every page I'd surely refund it...

Comment: I understand DRM "makes legitimate use harder", but this is what my employer wanted, I am just trying to accomplish the goal given to me.

Answer (score 0):

I used Ghostscript.Net (https://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET) to break up each page into a bitmap which you can
convert into any other format you want:

```
using Ghostscript.NET.Rasterizer;
...

using (GhostscriptRasterizer raster = new GhostscriptRasterizer())
{
    raster.Open(filename);
    pages = raster.PageCount;

    _bitpages = new Bitmap[raster.PageCount];
    for (int i = 1; i < pages + 1; i++)
    {
        _bitpages[i - 1] = (Bitmap)raster.GetPage(dpi, dpi, i);
        // convert and save image here
    }
    raster.Close();
}
```